# Texture variation on floor boards

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, workflow, unreal-engine

I'm trying to achieve a realistic look of some floor boards. I'm generating the floors using the Floor Generator add-on by Michel Anders. By using the 'Randomize UVs' checkbox I get an acceptable level of texture variation using one 512x512 diffuse map.

[image]

The problem is that it generates the UVs **outside of the 0 - 1 space**.

[image]

Importing this model into game engines like Unreal Engine 4 yields problems because it requires the model to have UVs mapped to the 0 - 1 space without overlapping as far as I know. My question is how do I achieve similar visuals regarding texture variation across the model without overlaps inside the 0 - 1 UV space without just scaling down the islands.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Try Pack Islands in UV Editor. I can see that UVs are overlaping in your example so if it's not a problem try it. Or you can try to scale it down but it will scale up diffuse map. Last option would be placing UV islands manually.

Comment: Tiling the texture in gimp so that it covers the whole UV map is out of the question I suppose?

Comment: The texture already covers the whole UV map. I think you mean tiling the texture so that the one 512 by 512 texture covers a 1024 by 1024 texture space (so pretty much quadrupled). That would be achievable I suppose. Any idea regarding the overlapping UVs? Packing the Islands is not doable because blender pretty much forces them into the space disregarding rotation and scale completely.